# Dont understand how this is improper syntax for global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
global player_hp = 500
global boss_hp = 1000
```

How do i write this so that i do not get a syntax error? If someone could help, i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `global` does not allow assigning a value at the same time. You have to do that separately. See [documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) You also only ever do this in a function, not the the module level. Python is not C++.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 2):

When you're assigning a variable, you don't use global. If the variable is defined outside of any functions etc. it is automatically global.

The global keyword could be used as follows to be able to write a global variable from inside a function.

```py
variable = 1

def foo():
    global variable
    variable = 2

print(variable) # 1
foo()
print(variable) # 2
```